# Live Camera Streaming (Red5, PHP)

Tags: php, live, red5, rtmp, amf

I'm creating live camera streaming application (php + red5). I will have multiple red5 servers and the thing is i will have to get all chat rooms and users online from all servers.
I'm considering 3 approches.

1. Getting all rooms, users online from each server and cache it for 5 seconds so data will not be retreived every request.
2. Updating database from the red5 application everytime someone creates room or enters one.
3. Calling web rest service from the red5 server everytime someone creates room or enters one. (I think it's best approach, since i can store data anywhere i want but i might be wrong)

I'm quite new to red5, that's why i'm asking for help with choosing the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution already. I've created custom HttpServlet that exposes red5 service. ;)

Comment: Hi ( szkoda, że nie można po polsku ;-) ) could You share Your solution? Right now I'm trying to create communication between apache server ( php ) and red5 server and honestly I don't really know where to start.

Comment: he does not give you his source code...
When he got problem he asked
but When He Got Solution He is :0